# I want a way to give path to my files which are outside of public folder in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, web

suppose `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">` helps to get style.css file  which is in public folder but  similarly how can I access file which is in resources folder.

Comment: You can link those files to the public folder. If you provide a link outside the public folder, the webserver can't serve this file, so this is impossible.

Comment: @sang-lu        I  have style.css in resources folder and I also have Vue js Components inside resources folder . Now I want to link that style.css   in my vue components. How can I?

Comment: you can open file `config/filesystems.php` and add a link in `links` array, after being added, you need to run `php artisan storage:link`. Now you will have a symbolic linked folder to your resources folder inside the public folder.

Comment: Assets under resources must go through Laravel Mix.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by another command for creating a symbolic link by terminal/cmd/shh:

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public /path/to/public/storage
```

This will create a folder in the public directory, which can be accessed from the public folder.